# Get the closest record for every date

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to create a query that returns all the prices from table `skucompetition` for every date in table `creationdateformat`.

To clarify, creationdateformat has these dates in it:

```
creationdateformat
2010-10-25
2010-10-26
2010-11-10
2010-11-24
2010-11-25
```

skucompetition has these prices for it:

```
sku              creationdate           price
PCR-BR2495112   2010-10-26 16:06:03    24.99
PCR-BR2495112   2010-11-10 13:01:43    27.99
PCR-BR2495112   2010-11-25 12:24:26    26.51
```

For date 2010-10-25 it should return 0, as it was before the first price existed.

For date 2010-10-26 it should return 24,99

For date 2010-11-10 and 2010-11-24 it should return 27.99

For date 2010-11-25 it should return 26.51

And so on.

How can this best be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand your example. All of the dates in your sample query are also in `creationdateformat`. What is the purpose of that table?

Comment: No no, not all of them. 2010-11-24 isn't on there. I'll make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction...

Judging from your sample data, you're looking for the **most recent** record either **before or on** a specific date.

You're only interested in a single record, so you should [limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4502537) your selection to the first record.

You can simplify the **before or on** part. Anything 'before or on today' is the same as anything 'before tomorrow'. So you'll be looking for anything 'before the input date [plus one day](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)'. This simplifies the query, because you won't have to worry about the exact time of day.

Finally, to make sure you get the **most recent** record, you'll have to [order](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) the records.

In pseudo-code it would be:

```
select the first record
from skucompetition
where creationdate is before (input date + one day)
order by creationdate so most recent record comes first
```

You should handle the special case of returning 0 in your application. If you have constructed the query correctly, it won't match any records for input dates before the first date. That's when your application should handle the 'return 0' case.

Comment: Oh, but I don't want the first record. I want them all. Every date with every price.

Comment: @skerit: I suggest you use a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html) to walk through the dates in `creationdateformat` and execute the query for each of these dates. Alternatively, you can walk through the dates in your application and execute the query from there, if you don't want to use a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a query that:

- selects all records with the creationdate on or later than the date you're looking at
- order those from the earliest to the latest
- and then use a "limit" to only return the first record

The exact syntax will of course depend on which RDBMS you use

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT price FROM skucompetition
WHERE sku = "<sku>" AND DATE(creationdate) <= "<date>"
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will select the first record with the right SKU that is not older than "date". If there's none, NULL will be returned.

Comment: `2010-10-26 16:06:03 <= "2010-10-26"` returns `0` which is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Danosaure I've changed it into DATE(creationdate) which should be fine. Note that DATE(column) doesn't play nice with an index, so actually you'd be better to use `creationdate < nextday` with `nextday` the day *after* date.